# How to remove the button active state when clicked

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a list of button groups.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <br />
  <div class="btn-group-toggle mr-2 p-4" data-toggle="buttons">
    <button
      *ngFor="let day of frequencyDays; let i = index"
      class="btn btn-primary mr-2"
      name="day_{{ i }}"
      [value]="day.id"
      type="button"
      (click)="onChangeCheckbox($event, day.id)"
      [ngClass]="{ active: checked(day.id) }"
      autocomplete="off"
    >
      {{ day.name }}
    </button>
  </div>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

On button click, I have added the value to the form control which is as form array using the following code.

```
  onChangeCheckbox(event: any, id: number) {
    const checkArray: FormArray = this.myForm.get(
      'frequencyInterval'
    ) as FormArray;

    let value = checkArray.value || [];
    if (value.some((e) => e === id)) {
      checkArray.removeAt(value.findIndex((item) => item === id));
    } else {
      checkArray.push(new FormControl(id));
    }

    // this.onChangeFrequencyInterval();
  }
```

formgroup is defined as:

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  frequency: [2, Validators.required],
  frequencyInterval: this.fb.array([2, 3]),
});
```

The problem in my case is whenever the view load initially the button state is active with the value in the frequency interval, which is fine.

But when I click on the button again, the value is removed from the form control, but the state of the button remains active.

I have called this function to check the state of the button:

```
   checked(id: number) {
    const checkArray: FormArray = this.myForm.get(
      'frequencyInterval'
    ) as FormArray;

    let value = checkArray.value || [];
    console.log('id', id);

    if (value.some((e) => e === id)) {
      console.log('add active');
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Working demo of **[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nh2q7s)**

Answer (score 1):

Based on data-toggle="buttons" attribute bootstrap.js doing some internal manipulation. You can workaround by removing `data-toggle="buttons"` from div.

```
<div class="btn-group-toggle mr-2 p-4" >
    <button
      *ngFor="let day of frequencyDays; let i = index;"
      class="btn btn-primary mr-2"
      name="day_{{ i }}"
      [value]="day.id"
      type="button"
      (click)="$event.stopPropagation();onChangeCheckbox($event, day.id)"
      [ngClass]="{ active: checked(day.id) }"
      autocomplete="off"
    > 
      {{ day.name }}
    </button> 
  </div>
```

**OR**

Add $event.stopPropagation on click event.

```
 <div class="btn-group-toggle mr-2 p-4" data-toggle="buttons">
    <button
      *ngFor="let day of frequencyDays; let i = index"
      class="btn btn-primary mr-2"
      name="day_{{ i }}"
      [value]="day.id"
      type="button"
      (click)="$event.stopPropagation();onChangeCheckbox($event, day.id)"
      [ngClass]="{ active: checked(day.id) }"
      autocomplete="off"
    >
      {{ day.name }}
    </button>
```

**[Forked Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3v6pxy?file=src/index.html)**

Comment: your fiddle has the same problem as in the question. may be you copy wrong URL

Comment: Updated but as mentioned in the answer you can remove data-toggle="buttons" from div element